# is this question for academia or linguistic part of SE?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

```
What is a difference between scientist and researcher?
```

I would like to know if this is adequate part of stack exchange forum to ask such a question or it is better to ask in English language part?

Comment: You know there are people who research things that aren't science, right? History. Art. Philosophy. etc. Those people are researchers and not scientists.

Comment: History is not a science????

Comment: History is traditionally considered one of the [humanities](http://shc.stanford.edu/what-are-the-humanities).

Comment: Science[nb 1] is a systematic enterprise that, using mathematics and measurement, creates, builds and organizes knowledge in the form of testable observations, explanations and predictions about the universe.[

Comment: even history of earth?

Comment: @ff524: Well, it is called a [social science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_science) by some. Unfortunately, the English word *science* is so diffuse that is almost useless.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

For example, if you want to know whether the word is appropriate to describe an activity on an English CV, Academia is more likely to give you answers from the perspective you are interested in.

If you are however interested how those words are perceived by native speakers of English (that are not necessarily academics), you will get a better answer on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). For example, you cannot expect answers on this site to elaborate on such terms as *researcher of the occult.*

Either way, I would not consider this question off-topic on Academia, but providing more context and asking it on the site fitting your context will help you to obtain better answers.

Comment: do I need to decide which one of those two, or it is allowed to ask same question on different SE? or only to change contex

Comment: @SSimon: Cross-posting is [generally frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/255554). If you really want to cover multiple perspectives, ask the question on one site and only when not all perspectives were addressed satisfyingly, ask it on the other site with special focus on those aspects and reference to the other question.